# How to enable --rs which is disabled by default

Tags: node.js, typescript, nats-streaming-server

How to enable --rs which is disabled by default in typescript,
I need to put this command in the start script

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the node modules directory of the nats-test directory,
and look for the ts-node-dev / bin / ts-node-dev folder, find the var

```
 var opts = minimist(devArgs, {
  stopEarly: true,
  boolean: [
    'all-deps',
    'deps',
    'dedupe',
    'poll',
    'respawn',
    'notify',
    'tree-kill',
    'clear',
    'cls',
    'exit-child',
    'error-recompile',
    // ts-node
    'dir',
    'scope',
    'emit',    
    'files',
    'pretty',
    'transpile-only',
    'prefer-ts-exts',
    'prefer-ts',
    'exec-check',
    'debug',
    'log-error',
    'skip-project',
    'skip-ignore',
    'compiler-host',
    'script-mode'
  ]....

**and add rs**



 var opts = minimist(devArgs, {
      stopEarly: true,
      boolean: [
        'rs',
        'all-deps',
        'deps',
        'dedupe',
        'poll',
        'respawn',
        'notify',
        'tree-kill',
        'clear',
        'cls',
        'exit-child',
        'error-recompile',
        // ts-node
        'dir',
        'scope',
        'emit',    
        'files',
        'pretty',
        'transpile-only',
        'prefer-ts-exts',
        'prefer-ts',
        'exec-check',
        'debug',
        'log-error',
        'skip-project',
        'skip-ignore',
        'compiler-host',
        'script-mode'
      ],
```